# Can't resolve Gemfile.lock merge error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, gemfile.lock

I tried to run bundle install and this happens, and I can't see to fix it. I don't think there are any merge conflicts in my gem file that I haven't fixed.. but I still can't get rid of this error. How can I do so?

Your Gemfile.lock contains merge conflicts.

Run `git checkout HEAD -- Gemfile.lock` first to get a clean lock.

this is my gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.8'

group :test, :development do
    gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :test do
    gem 'capybara'
    #gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group(:development, :test) do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
end

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.2'

# add bootstrap gem
gem 'bootstrap-sass'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

gem 'rubyzip', '0.9.9'
```

Comment: did you have a look into your Gemfile.lock?

Comment: thank you for the reply. I found that I could resolve it just by editing the hemlock file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually very straightforward. Here is an article that explains the difference between the gemfile and the gemfile.lock. (You can edit Gemfile.lock to get rid of the conflicts manually)

http://rubyinrails.com/2013/12/what-is-gemfile-lock/